# How to implement Bottom Tab bar in mobile websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

[image]
*Bottom navbar in LinkedIn*

What is the tech behind this.how to implement it in web pages?
If any any framework like react or angular is needed please mention it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this thing

```css
.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;  
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Hope this Help

Answer (score 3):

you don’t need any framework to do that really.

Attaching HTML dom-nodes to the page is done quite easily with the use of CSS `position: fixed`

This fixes an HTML element to the view layer above other elements. Let me show you an example:

```css
#fixme {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixme">I’m fixed</div>
<p>Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the pageSome random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page Some random text to fill the page</p>
```

See how the `I’m fixed` div is fixed above everything else?

- `position: fixed` fixes the element in place
- `bottom: 0` = places the element at the bottom of the page
- `z-index: 999` positions the div on a `z-index` of value `999` this can be anything really, as long as it is a higher number than anything else.

You’ll also need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to differentiate whether it is a small screen size or a large one.

*PS: I would suggest you check out some beginner tutorials on web development. Especially html+css in your case.*

Welcome to the web development community :)